# How to remove Post ID from posts and then redirect to new URL?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, wordpress

I just changed the permalink structure of my wordrpress based blog. Previously it had the permalink structure like this

http://www.mysite.com/sample-post-example/2345/

The numbers at the end of the url were automatically generated by wordpress software. In fact these numbers are post_id. Now I have this url structure.

http://www.mysite.com/sample-post-example/

Now the problem is that the individual posts are available under both url structures.

Is there anyway to redirect (301) old URLs to new url after removing the Post_ID present at the end of the old URL??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule (.+)/\d{4,5}/?$ $1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I just found that this these lines are also causing a serious problem to pagination. Like when I go to http://www.example.com/page/2/ to go to next page, I found 404 error because the above rules remove the number at the end of URL and convert them to http://www.example.com/page/ only. Any solution to this problem??

Comment: What structure has URL with page number?

Comment: I run a wordpress blog with the homepage containing the last 13 posts on frontpage. The homepage then has pagination to go to previous posts. So when I try to go to page number 2, which is like http://www.mysite.com/page/2/, I receive 404 errors due to above lines. Now I am using two lines and every thing is working fine on my blog. Please check them out and tell me is there anything wrong with these codes.

Comment: I can't use the "Enter" key in comments, so I have posted a answer below. Please check it out.

Comment: So you want to cut only if the digit contains from 4 or 5 digits? I'll correct my answer if that is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot once again. I didnt try it yet but I hope I will work.

Comment: This worked like charm. But could you please do another favour?/ Can you tell me who to redirect non-www to www version?

Comment: Hi, can I also exclude some number from this redirect?? For instance I don't want to apply the redirection rule to a post which ends with 57435 and leave it as it is. I highly appreciate your help.

Comment: Add RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !your_digits/$ before last rule

Comment: Hi, here is one more problem, if you could help me. As per your above reply I used RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !your_digits/$ to exclude some pages from the 301 redirect rule. But after using this statement, there are few URLS at my site which end with two sets of digits like this one. http://www.mysite.com/download-the-whole-video-of-steve-jobs-keynotes-from-wwdc-2010-55446/ Now if I use 55446 in exclusion list, then the redirect statement also removes 2010 digit which causes a redirect loop. Is there any way to keep 2010 but remove 55446?

Comment: I think it will look like: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !55446/$ [OR] RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*2010.*`. That will pass any URL with 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Individual posts should not be available under both URLs. Are you sure the second link you posted is not the archive page?
This is probably the custom permalink structure you are looking for: /%category%/%postname%

Answer (score 0):

I run a wordpress blog with the homepage containing the last 13 posts on frontpage. The homepage then has pagination to go to previous posts. So when I try to go to page number 2, which is like http://www.mysite.com/page/2/, I receive 404 errors due to above lines. Now I am using two lines and every thing is working fine on my blog. Please check them out and tell me is there anything wrong with these codes.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+)/([0-9]{4})/$ http://www.mysite.com/$1
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+)/([0-9]{5})/$ http://www.mysite.com/$1
```

I have maximum ~1000 blog posts which make 74 pages. But the ID of the first post contains 4 digit number and the last post which I created with the ID at the end of the URL contains 5 digit number. So the first line check whether the post contains 4 digit number at the end of the URL, if yes it will remove them and display the remaining part which is /sample-post-example/ as described above. Similarly the second line detects the 5 digit number at the end of the url. The other URLs which contain less or more than 4-5 digit will remain unaffected. In this way the pagination of front page remains unaffected.

Can we combine the above two lines??

Sorry, eng is not my native language, so I think I couldn't tell you in a proper way.